# Finding P(A|C, B)

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian

hope you can help me out, I've searched through earlier answers but still haven't been able to solve my problem.  This is for an assignment.

I need to find 
$
P(A|C,~B)
$

I know that:
$
P(A|C,~B)=\frac{P(C|A,~B)P(A|B)}{P(C|B)}
$

I've calculated from the information provided
$
P(B)
$
,
$
P(not~B)
$
,
$
P(A)
$
,
$
P(B|A)
$

I've also been provided with the answers to
$
P(A|B)
$
,
$
P(A|not~B)
$
,
$
P(C|A,~B)
$
and
$
P(C|A,~not~B)
$

This is as far as I've gotten on my own.

Is it possible knowing this information to find 
$
P(C)
$
and/or 
$
P(C|B)
$
and if so how please?

Comment: Conceptually, something to realize in Bayes rule $P(X \mid Y) = \frac{P( Y \mid X)P(X)}{P(Y)}$ is that the denominator $P(Y)$ is basically a normalizing constant so that $\sum_Y P(Y \mid X) = 1$ (i.e. the probabilities sum to 1 rather than something else).

Comment: Hint: $P(C \mid A,B)P(A\mid B) = ?$ And then what variable can you sum over to get $P(C \mid B)$?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  So are you saying that if $P(Y|X)=0.531$(for example) then $\sum_Y=1/0.531\approx 1.883$?

Comment: No? I don't understand what you're doing there? I'm saying $\sum_{y} P(X = x, Y= y) = P(X = x)$ For example, if $Y$ were a binary variable that takes the values $T$ or $F$ we'd have $P(X =x, Y=T) + P(X=x, Y=F) = P(X=x)$. This is called computing the [marginal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) or marginalizing out a variable.

Comment: The following notation is closer to your actual situation/problem: Let $A^c$ denote the complement of event $A$, (that is, let $A^c$ denote not $A$). Then $P(CA) + P(CA^c) = P(C)$.